# Conversion of sh script to perl script

Tags: perl

Good afternoon, I wrote a shell script for below scenario:

Find all files of today and read those and get the sixth field separated by ~

```
================
#!/usr/bin/ksh
DATE=`date | awk '{print $2 " " $3}'`
TIMESTAMP=`date +"%m%d%Y"`
for filename in `ls -ltr | grep -i "$DATE"| awk '{print $9}'`
do
  cat $filename | grep -i ^01 | awk -F'~' '{print $6}' >> /tmp/log.$TIMESTAMP
done
================
```

Can someone please provide a perl equavalent for this.

Comment: You can run those very same shell commands in perl, using `system()`

Comment: `cat $filename | grep -i ^01` could be written as `grep -i ^01 "$filename`

Comment: `date | awk '{print $2 " " $3}'` can be written as `date +"%b %d"`

Comment: try using http://search.cpan.org/~clive/App-sh2p-0.04/lib/App/sh2p.pod

Comment: @kjprice - `grep -i ^01 $filename | awk -F~ '{print $6}'` can be written `<$filename awk -F~ '/^01/{print $6}'`

Comment: -1 I should comment that this is a disgraceful question. Stack Overflow isn't a free software factory: it is here to help out programmers who mostly know what they are doing but have come across an insurmountable problem that baffles them. Here, you appear to have made no effort whatsoever to solve your problem. Please read [What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/). The task isn't too hard, and I guess from that that you know no Perl at all so were *really* hoping for a freebie here. Well that is what you got. The problem interested me so I wrote an answer. Please don't do it again.

Comment: @runrig I was expecting that...I don't know any awk. ;)

Comment: @runrig: How does that help us towards a Perl solution?

Comment: @Borodin - Well, my comment was directed at kjprice...but the closer we get to pure awk, the closer we get to being able to use [a2p](http://perldoc.perl.org/a2p.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think this does the trick, although my Korn shell is very rusty.

It differs by checking the actual modification time against the previous midnight instead of searching for the month and day in an `ls` listing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find 'find';
use Time::Piece 'localtime';

my $timestamp = localtime->strftime('%m%d%Y');
my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($timestamp, '%m%d%Y')->epoch;

open my $log, '>', "/tmp/log.$timestamp" or die "Unable to open log file: $!";

find(sub {
  return unless -f and (stat)[9] >= $date;
  open my $fh, '<', $_ or die qq{Unable to open "$_" for reading: $!};
  while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    next unless /^01/;
    print $log (split /~/)[5], "\n";
  }
}, '.');
```

Comment: Nice solution. But  I think `use POSIX` is more simple instead of Time::Piece. Using `localtime` and `mktime` is more unixisch, so I would use it instead.

Comment: @TrueY: I disagree and suggest you submit an answer of your own. `POSIX` is an *enormous* and cumbersome module, and mostly unnecessary.

Comment: I used `POSIX` module a lot and I did not met any problems. And it is part of the basic install. Could You add an url describing the problems?

Comment: @TrueY - Borodin said it's an enormous module...loads many function just so you can use a few. Time::Piece has strftime AND strptime (POSIX does not have strptime) making BOTH parsing and formatting datetimes simple and elegant.

Comment: @runrig: Thanx! Making a string from local time and then convert it to a time is worst (I suppose) then create a time directly with `mktime`. The `use POSIX qw(mktime);` is not a solution not to load all the stuff defined in POSIX module?

Comment: @TrueY: You have made your point of view perfectly clear. I disagree with you. Please stop commenting and post a solution that you think is superior.

Comment: @Borodin: I'm really very sorry, that You misinterpreted my intentions. I'm happy that I could learn the `File::Find` solution from You. So I gave my +1 to You. But I'm not sure that the time conversion is as efficient as it can be. I would like to know the truth. As I cannot post my new answer I post my measures here. I did `use POSIX 'mktime'; my $date1 = mktime(0, 0, 0, (localtime)[3..8]);`. I run Your and my solution 1000 times in a `bash` `for` loop and I use `time` to measure. Your: 45.385s/25.329s/18.663s, mine: 39.574s/20.956s/17.227s, empty perl script: 22.359s/10.659s/10.686s.

Comment: @Borodin: One more issue I found. I think Your version uses UTC and not local time. I measured a 7200s difference in `$date` and the `date +%s -d 00:00` matches with the `mkitime` result.

Comment: @TrueY - Did you include the load time of POSIX? Nevermind, it's really just a matter of who thinks what is simpler. Also, updated post to fix UTC issue.

Comment: @runrig: Yes, it is a complete time of the perl script with parsing all modules (*1000). I fully agree with You about the favourite-tools staff. The issue was that POSIX is _enormous and cumbersome_. I thought it is an rather tiny interface to glibc, so my assumption was that it is faster to use. Actually its code is pretty small, as it really calls C code. `Time::Piece` is a kind of reimplementation of `mktime` related functions, so I assume it is more portable, then `POSIX`, but I have no such experience.

Comment: Well, my update was wrong...epoch time was not truncated to day, but if you use the localtime as a prototype to strptime() (instead of the classname 'Time::Piece'), then the result is local, not UTC. Will leave any updates to someone else...

Answer (score -2):

```
open KSH, "| /usr/bin/ksh";
print KSH <<'EOF';
DATE=`date | awk '{print $2 " " $3}'`
TIMESTAMP=`date +"%m%d%Y"`
for filename in `ls -ltr | grep -i "$DATE"| awk '{print $9}'`
do
  cat $filename | grep -i ^01 | awk -F'~' '{print $6}' >> /tmp/log.$TIMESTAMP
done
EOF
close KSH;
```

Anything else would not quite be equivalent.

Comment: -1: this is really what was asked, but the original script is very bad.